# Firefox OS 1.3 Simulator 7.0pre9.20140401 does not connect in firefox 32

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-os

I'm trying to have my hands on firefox OS.

I've updated my Firefox browser to lateset version at this time i.e v32.

I've also installed the Firefox OS 1.3 Simulator 7.0pre9.20140401 (Stable) from [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/labs/fxos-simulator/) but when I try to connect the simulator from app-manager it says 'Simulator not installed' and does not get connected.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: If you install the 1.4 and 2.0 simulators do they show up when you click the start simulator button?  Do either of them connect?

Comment: @JasonWeathersby No nothing shows up. It always says that simulator is not installed, no matter what I do.

Comment: If you select tools->addons do any of the simulators show up there?  Are they enabled?